# Rails 5 API - saving data using virtual attributes does not save data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model which exposes a field called 'body' in the api. The user submit json including that field, and it should get saved to a field called 'custom_body' in the database.

If custom_body is empty, then I use i18n to return a default string for the 'body' field.

This is the model:

```
class Reminder < ApplicationRecord
  # Relationships
  belongs_to :user

  def body=(value)
    self.custom_body = value
  end

  def body
    custom_body.presence || I18n.t('reminder.default_body', name: self.user.name)
  end
end
```

The controller is scaffolded so standard and works fine. Here is the update action:

```
  # PATCH/PUT /reminders/1
  def update
    if @reminder.update(reminder_params)
      render json: @reminder
    else
      render json: @reminder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

and here are the whitelisted params:

```
# Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
def reminder_params
  params.require(:reminder).permit( :id, :user_id, :subject, :greeting, :body, :is_follow_up)
end
```

The problem is the default returns fine, but when the user submits 'body' it does not get persisted into 'custom_body', which I thought is solved by this method:

```
  def body=(value)
    self.custom_body = value
  end
```

It works in [this](https://gorails.com/episodes/virtual-attributes-and-rails-5-attribute-api) gorails cast (see 10 min mark), so what am I missing?

Comment: You set the value with `self.custom_body = value`. But when/where do you save the record?

Comment: Does the method get overwritten by Rails's generated methods? Are you able to use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) or similar to inspect the `body=` method's source in the console?

Comment: You need to save after setting value to `self.custom_body = value` and next line `save!`

Comment: Oh I thought Rails took care of this automatically when saving

Comment: @7urkm3n I tired self.save! but still custom_body does not get saved.

Comment: not `self.save!` just `save!` or `save(validate: false)`

Comment: I've tried save! save save(validate: false) self.save self.save! and none of them work. Examples I see elsewhere do not require an explicit save - it just works when controller update action fires.

Comment: can u post yr controller where calling the body method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166979/discussion-between-7urkm3n-and-rmcsharry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else stumbles on this question the Rails code is correct.

The problem here was strong parameters. In the controller notice the require:

```
def reminder_params
  params.require(:reminder).permit( :id, :user_id, :subject, :greeting, :body, :is_follow_up)
end
```

The json body of the patch request therefore must be structured like this:

{ "reminder": 
  { ... all the fields ... }
}

The client was just sending a list of fields and not putting them inside the 'reminder' object.

For example, it needs to be like this:

```
Parameters: 
{"reminder"=>
  {"subject"=>"your checklist reminder!", 
   "greeting"=>"Hi", 
   "body"=>"\nThis is a quick reminder about the outstanding items still on your checklist.\n\nPlease click the button below to review the items we're still waiting on.\n\nThank you,\n\nRichard Owner",
   "id"=>"33b29a76-298f-4ef2-a76a-ca4438c6d1ce"
  }
}
```